# Set text field min and max value based on the option selected in previous dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a drop down and a text box next to it.
When some value is selected in the dropdown, the textbox should allow min and max characters based on the selected option.
Suppose I select option 1, then the textbox next to it should allow minimum 10 characters and max 16 characters.

How to achieve it?

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="required">Select Type</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="prooftype">
        <option value="0" disabled> </option>
        <option value="name1">name1</option>
        <option value="name2">name2</option>
        <option value="name3">name3</option>
        <option value="name4">name4</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group md-form">
      <label class="required" for="id" data-error="wrong" data-success="right">
        <i class="fa fa-info pr-2"></i> 
        Enter Identity Card Number
      </label>
      <input id="id" type="number" minlength="3" class="form-control validate" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return blockSpecialChar(event)" oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" maxlength="20" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527), if you have a problem, please post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read ['How to Ask a good question' guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Question Do's and Don'ts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527), and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

you have to change a little your code

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="required">Select Type</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="prooftype">
        <option value="0/0" disabled> </option>
        <option value="10/16">name1</option>
        <option value="20/32">name2</option>
        <option value="30/48">name3</option>
        <option value="40/64">name4</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group md-form">
      <label class="required" for="id" data-error="wrong" data-success="right">
        <i class="fa fa-info pr-2"></i> 
        Enter Identity Card Number
      </label>
      <input id="id" type="text" minlength="3" class="form-control validate" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return blockSpecialChar(event)"  maxlength="20" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and jQuery

```
$('#prooftype').change(function(){

var tmp = $(this).val().split('/');
    $('input#id').attr('minlength',tmp[0]).attr('maxlength',tmp[1]);

})
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do is when a particular option is selected, the textbox should change its min and max character acceptance lenght

Comment: The option should have only 1 value. i.e name1 or name2 or name3 or name4

Comment: with which criteria have to change te values of minlenght and maxlength according to value name1, i.e. for value name2 what values should be applied in input attribute? in my answer i put Min and Max value directly as option value so i can get them easily

Comment: The validations did not work, also i got value as 12/16 in the backend. which should be name1

Comment: The validation is another thing, you asked for how to edit dom attributes by changing a select. the text that is already typed into the fields does not affected by the new value of minlenght and maxlenght, you have to write your own validation function to trigger when the form i submitted

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the the option value of `12/16` to the backend, obviously the data will reflect. I think you need something like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="required">Select Type</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="prooftype">
        <option value="0/0" disabled> </option>
        <option value="name1">name1</option>
        <option value="name2">name2</option>
        <option value="name3">name3</option>
        <option value="name4">name4</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group md-form">
      <label class="required" for="id" data-error="wrong" data-success="right">
        <i class="fa fa-info pr-2"></i> 
        Enter Identity Card Number
      </label>
      <input id="inputid" type="text" minlength="3" class="form-control validate" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return blockSpecialChar(event)"  maxlength="20" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And your JQuery

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var selectedopt;

$('#prooftype').change(function(){
   selectedopt=  $(this).val();

   //Add your condition here, and  check the selected option value:
  if(selectedopt== "name1")
  {
   //Set input min and max value based on the selected option value.
   $('#inputid').attr('minlength','10').attr('maxlength','16');
  }
  elseif(selectedopt== "name2")
  {
   $('#inputid').attr('minlength','20').attr('maxlength','25');
  }
  // And so on........
})


</script>
```